# Removing code duplicate with if constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17

I have some code as follows:

```
    Matrix<T, N> res = zeros<T, N>(dims);
    if constexpr (N1 == 1) {
        MatrixView<U, 2> m1_view ({1, m1.dims[0]}, m1.dataView(), {m1.dims[0], 1});
        if constexpr (N2 == 1) {
            MatrixView<V, 2> m2_view ({m2.dims[0], 1}, m2.dataView(), {1, 1});
            // duplicate code! yuck..
            res.applyFunctionWithBroadcast(m1_view, m2_view, MatmulTo<U, V, T,
                    std::min(std::max(N1, 2lu), N - 1),
                    std::min(std::max(N2, 2lu), N - 1), N - 1>);
        } else {
            MatrixView<V, N2> m2_view (m2);
            res.applyFunctionWithBroadcast(m1_view, m2_view, MatmulTo<U, V, T,
                    std::min(std::max(N1, 2lu), N - 1),
                    std::min(std::max(N2, 2lu), N - 1), N - 1>);
        }
    } else {
        MatrixView<U, N1> m1_view (m1);
        if constexpr (N2 == 1) {
            MatrixView<V, 2> m2_view ({m2.dims[0], 1}, m2.dataView(), {1, 1});
            // duplicate code! yuck..
            res.applyFunctionWithBroadcast(m1_view, m2_view, MatmulTo<U, V, T,
                    std::min(std::max(N1, 2lu), N - 1),
                    std::min(std::max(N2, 2lu), N - 1), N - 1>);
        } else {
            MatrixView<V, N2> m2_view (m2);
            res.applyFunctionWithBroadcast(m1_view, m2_view, MatmulTo<U, V, T,
                    std::min(std::max(N1, 2lu), N - 1),
                    std::min(std::max(N2, 2lu), N - 1), N - 1>);
        }
    }
    return res;
```

which can be simplified in languages like Python (but not in C++):

```
    if constexpr (N1 == 1) {
        MatrixView<U, 2> m1_view ({1, m1.dims[0]}, m1.dataView(), {m1.dims[0], 1});
    } else {
        MatrixView<U, N1> m1_view (m1);
    }
    if constexpr (N2 == 1) {
        MatrixView<V, 2> m2_view ({m2.dims[0], 1}, m2.dataView(), {1, 1});
    } else {
        MatrixView<V, N2> m2_view (m2);
    }
    // doesn't compile
    res.applyFunctionWithBroadcast(m1_view, m2_view, MatmulTo<U, V, T,
        std::min(std::max(N1, 2lu), N - 1),
        std::min(std::max(N2, 2lu), N - 1), N - 1>);
    return res;
```

`MatrixView` is not default constructible. (It is basically a non-owning view for some `Matrix`, therefore allowing so will break design)

The code above is logically valid but it won't compile, so I wrote the first ugly, verbose code.

Is there any way to remove code duplication in situations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might do:

```
auto m1_view = [&](){
    if constexpr (N1 == 1) {
        return MatrixView<U, 2>({1, m1.dims[0]}, m1.dataView(), {m1.dims[0], 1});
    } else {
        return MatrixView<U, N1>(m1);
    }
}(); // notice extra () to immediate call
auto m2_view = [&](){
    if constexpr (N2 == 1) {
        return MatrixView<V, 2>({m2.dims[0], 1}, m2.dataView(), {1, 1});
    } else {
        return MatrixView<V, N2>(m2);
    }
}();
Matrix<T, N> res = zeros<T, N>(dims);
res.applyFunctionWithBroadcast(m1_view, m2_view, MatmulTo<U, V, T,
        std::min(std::max(N1, 2lu), N - 1),
        std::min(std::max(N2, 2lu), N - 1), N - 1>);
return res;
```